# Morphia. I don't know, how correctly use isStoreEmpties()

Tags: morphia

```
public static Datastore morphiaSessionFactoryUtil() {
    MongoClientOptions.Builder options = new MongoClientOptions.Builder();
    options.connectionsPerHost(200); //max pool size
    MongoClient mongoClient = new MongoClient(new ServerAddress("localhost", 3001), options.build());
    Morphia morphia = new Morphia();
    morphia.getMapper().getOptions().setStoreEmpties(true);     //good work!!
    morphia.getMapper().getOptions().isStoreEmpties();         //don't work, because return false
    morphia.mapPackage("ru.stqa.pft.itgen.model");
    Datastore datastore = morphia.createDatastore(mongoClient, "meteor");

    return datastore;
}
```

I have this code, it works good on old method `setStoreEmpties()`. But I don't want to use it.

How to correctly use `isStoreEmpties()`? What have I to add in my code?

`morphia.getMapper().getOptions().isStoreEmpties();` must to return `true` (in my project).

[image in debug](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Cr5p.jpg)

Comment: What version of morphia are you using?

Comment: this works just fine for me on the 1.6.x branch

Comment: I'm using morphia 1.5.8

Comment: I can't reproduce this in any environment.  I've tried three different versions even.  This is a pretty fundamental core piece of functionality.  If it were broken, there are are unit tests that would have found that.  I don't know what to tell you here.

Comment: morphia.getMapper().getOptions().setStoreEmpties(true); - return true,     morphia.getMapper().getOptions().isStoreEmpties(); - return false (I added picture) . My project don't work correctly (how I want) if the method returns false. How I need use isStoreEmpties() that it return true?

Comment: can you take a look at this repo?  https://github.com/evanchooly/morphia_storeEmpties  it's essentially the code above dropped in to the morphia-reproducer project trying to recreate this.  Can you spot anything different than what you're doing?

Comment: I looked this repo. If I delete morphia.getMapper().getOptions().setStoreEmpties(true);   test failed. Problem that method setStoreEmpties will absent in next versions and I want use only .isStoreEmpties().

Comment: There is not reason to use `isStoreEmpties()` directly.  Building your app to depend on such details is a bug, IMO.  In 2.0, storing empties or not is still avalaible.  It's simple done via a builder not on the MapperOptions itself.